# Build error on the server

Tags: .net, jenkins, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm getting following error when building the net code(using Jenkins) on the server:

> "SGEN : error : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>   Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"

(My code does use Nuget packages to reference the dlls.)

I don't get this error when building the code using Visual Studio 2015 IDE on my local machine.

As a resolution, I tried setting CopyLocal to true for all the referenced dlls in my project but no luck.
Also, I changed the Specific Version Property of the Refrences to false but still it didnt work.

Not sure how do i resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "SGEN : error : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"

If using serialization assemblies is not your requirement, **you can set "Generate serialization assembly" to "Off"**. Go to Project Properties->Build->Generate serialization assembly, set the value to "Off" instead of "Auto".

Source [Debugging SGEN LoaderExceptions errors](http://hashtagfail.com/post/5255977780/sgen-loaderexceptions-error):

> The reason why this happens is that in Release builds, Visual Studio
>   attempts to generate a serialization assembly containing the types in
>   your solution, to improve XmlSerializer serialization performance,
>   should you choose to serialize your types. This can be disabled by
>   going to the Build tab of the project properties and setting "Generate
>   serialization assembly" to "Off".

After save this setting, then upload project to the Jenkins server to check if it works.